# Please don't forget to upvote questions

Tags: discussion

If questions are even reasonably acceptable -- basically, if we're going to have them open for answers -- they deserve at least a couple of upvotes.  Not only is it nice to do, but the whole SE system breaks down if nothing gets upvoted.

I just went through 4 questions from the last couple days that were reasonably well-formed, and nobody other than me upvoted them, even though a couple of our regular contributors answered them.